# Why is var_dump displaying NULL when accessing a key that has an array as a value?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, themes

I'm trying to loop through the Wordpress themes I have installed to pull out a piece of data. I need to get access to $value->headers["TextDomain"] but when I try to access $value->headers I get a `NULL` response.

Here is the Wordpress Theme Object array that I am trying to pull data from:

```
object(WP_Theme)#795 (12) {
  ["update"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["theme_root":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  string(56) "/Users/tygoss/Projects/QuickPress/prod/wp-content/themes"
  ["headers":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(10) "Black Jane"
    ["ThemeURI"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Description"]=>
    string(187) "Black Jane is a clean SuevaFree child theme with an optional slideshow on homepage, a new header layout in addition to the five header layouts available on SuevaFree and new Google Fonts."
    ["Author"]=>
    string(16) "ThemeinProgress."
    ["AuthorURI"]=>
    string(31) "https://www.themeinprogress.com"
    ["Version"]=>
    string(5) "1.0.4"
    ["Template"]=>
    string(9) "suevafree"
    ["Status"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Tags"]=>
    string(302) "blog, e-commerce, photography, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-logo, custom-menu, featured-images, flexible-header, footer-widgets, post-formats, right-sidebar, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready, one-column, two-columns, three-columns, grid-layout"
    ["TextDomain"]=>
    string(10) "black-jane"
    ["DomainPath"]=>
    string(10) "/languages"
  }
  ["name_translated":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  NULL
  ["errors":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  NULL
  ["stylesheet":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  string(10) "black-jane"
  ["template":"WP_Theme":private]=>
  string(9) "suevafree"
}
```

If I var_dump( $value->stylesheet ) I get `string(10) "black-jane"`

But if I var_dump ( $value->headers ) I get `NULL`

Here is my loop:

```
    $all_themes = wp_get_themes();
    foreach ($all_themes as $key => $value) {
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($value->headers);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Shouldn't $value->headers dump out an array of 11 items? Why is it returning `NULL` and why does $value->stylesheet work but not $value-headers?

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like there is the `__get()` magic method implemented in the `WP_Theme` class which have a switch statement where the header attribute is not defined and the default case is to return null, and you can try to use `get( $header )` method to have access to those attributes .. so try with `var_dump($value->get("TextDomain"));` src : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php#L0 . it does not seams to have a method to return all the headers but i maybe did not dig enough

Comment: @Frankich that worked! My final code is:

`$all_themes = wp_get_themes();
    $theme_slugs = array();
    foreach ($all_themes as $key => $value) { 
      array_push($theme_slugs, $value->get("TextDomain"));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

`$value->get("the thing from the header array")` works flawlessly!